# Azure Python: installing azure-storage python library issues

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am getting this issue after calling pip install azure-storage -t app/lib:

```
No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time
```

I created a folder called lib within a webapp virtualenv to install all the libraries and dependencies.

When checking the folder cryptography.hazmat.bindings, there is a file called _constant_time.so.

If I install azure-storage with python, it works fine.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Any advice would be grateful. Thank you!

Comment: hm, I've done the exact same thing couple of days ago, it worked like a charm, did you try it on some other pc?

Comment: hmm. I do this on a mac.

Comment: well, I just did the same on my win10. works fine. try another box\vm.

Comment: @tipsywacky, I tried to reproduce the issue via do the same thing on my mac, but failed, works fine. I think you can try to reinstall pip via commands `sudo easy_install -m pip` and `sudo easy_install install pip`, and check your environment or conflict with the same name file.

Comment: actually forget about this, there is a difference in the python environment that I am using.